# X11 window manager: Minimize window using modifier+mouse

Tags: linux, window-manager, desktop-environment

Back in the day, with Motif or IRIX’s 4Dwm, I used Alt+Mouse-R to minimize the window under the mouse pointer. There also was Alt+Mouse-L to move and Alt+Mouse-M to resize, configured in `.mwmrc` or so.
With Xfce, Moving and Resizing is still possible and I use Hyper (a.k.a Windows) + Mouse-L/R for it. But the minimize shortcut remains a mystery.

I did not find it in KDE’s window manager, either. Haven’t tried others yet.

How do I get that function back in any of the current Linux desktop environments?

If there is anyone here who contributes to those: Why was this old and useful MWM feature *disinvented*?